# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference causing a crash

Tags: java, android

My app keeps crashing and the logcat gives me the most specific detail when talking about MainActivity line 23. The error reads:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.paintcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
```

and my MainActivity Code on line 23 is:

```
buttonPaint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       openPaint();
    }
...
```

Images of these are attached

[MainActivity code at error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpHe0.png)

[logcat exception thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEAEn.png)

Comment: Double check if `btnOpenPaint` is actually a valid id of the button.

Comment: Make sure the XML has the button and you're using the same xml. `findViewById` returns null if the view does not exists in your view hierarchy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) I agree with @Qunata: make sure you are using the correct xml file and that the Button in the xml file has the same id as the Button in your code. That being said, please post text as text and not as picture. It's easier to read, search and copy-paste that way - even if you don't want to have it read to you by a machine

Comment: Thank you for the replies and the help. I've looked at the XML file and here I have the button btnOpenPaint  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOpenPaint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnPaint"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnOpenCarpet"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.109"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrain...